# Laravel Livewire, how to send the value of an option tag to wire:model=" category"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a select element in cart.blade file like this:

```
<select wire:model="category">
   @foreach ($categories as $item)
      <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

and when I selected an item from the list, it will not send the value of the option tag to the category variable in the component (just sends the sorted numbers of selected options starts from 1 to n).

how to send the value of an option tag to wire:model=" category"?

Comment: Try put name="category" in the select

Comment: and how to sync it with the category var in the component like wire:model="category"?

Comment: try to inspect the dom and see if the value attributes are set to only the ids, and check the category variable, it can not be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind trying the following?

```
class GroupMoney extends Component
{
    public $category_id;
    public $category;

    public function updatedcategory($value)
    {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $this->category_id = category::find($value);
        }
    }
}
```